# How to change error message of the webform

Tags: 7, webforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [preprocess_node_webform is not working](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39753/preprocess-node-webform-is-not-working)

How can I change the default error message of the webform ? For example "The name field is required"  to  "Please enter your name". Where should I make changes to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [drupal_set_message()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7).